# How to let the user to input string as well as integers in my program?

Tags: python

I have a question. how can I let the user to enter 'quit' (A string) in my program as well as integers? Thank you

```py
message = "Please enter your age.\nEnter quit to exit the program.\n"
age = ""

while age != 'quit':
    age = input(messages)

    if age == 'quit':
        break

    age = int(age)
    
    elif age < 3:
        print("The ticket you purchased is free.")
    elif age >= 3 and age < 13:
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $10.")
    elif age >= 13:
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $15.")
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code right now?

Comment: Your code seems to work if you replace `messages` with `message`, and the first `elif` with `if`

Comment: @TheThonnu You can't put statements between `if` and `elif` so, no, it doesn't work.

Comment: There is a typo in `input(messages)`, `messages` is not defined, but `message` is.

Comment: @matszwecja - ok, I updated my comment

Answer (score 2):

Your code is close to working, but there are two issues:

```py
message = "Please enter your age.\nEnter quit to exit the program.\n"
age = ""

while age != 'quit':
    age = input(message)  # variable is called message

    if age == 'quit':
        break

    age = int(age)
    
    if age < 3:  # start a new if/elif/else block
        print("The ticket you purchased is free.")
    elif age >= 3 and age < 13:
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $10.")
    elif age >= 13:
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $15.")
```

I'd also simplify the if/elif/else block to

```py
    if age < 3:
        print("The ticket you purchased is free.")
    elif age < 13:  # no need for >= 3 check since that is done above
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $10.")
    else:  # no need for final check since all special cases done above
        print("The ticket you purchased cost $15.")
```